# Getting a Guzzle 401 error when deploying a composer enable site to production?

Tags: php, jquery, composer-php

I have a site that uses composer to build the QA environment and then deploys the QA environment to production.  Production does not have composer installed, instead the vendor folder is synced between the two environments.  On my last project I had to update the composer.lock file.  When i deployed the project, i received the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: GET https://www.myurl.com resulted in a 401 Unauthorized response:
Unauthorized.
 in my_file_system/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
Stack trace:
#0 my_file_system/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 my_file_system/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#2 my_file_system/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#3 my_file_system/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#4 my_file_system/ in my_file_system/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 113, referer:
```

The error is happening during an JQuery AJAX call.  Any deployment that i do to a system that has composer seems to work correctly, it is only when the system does not have the ability to run composer commands that error is seen.

I have been unable to duplicate the issue in a testing environment up to this point and can test in production.

Comment: This error seems to have originate from your use of Guzzle instead of composer. 401 error indicates that the server you requested ("https: // www.myurl.com") don't allow you to retrieve its content. Could it be a problem with overwritting configuration file (e.g. `.env`) when you re-deploy?

Comment: @KoalaYeung - you are correct. that did end up being the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being an incorrect value in the .env file.